# anywork around for running Azure devops Test plans for javascript tests?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

Currently Azure devops maynot work with javascript tests.
Has anyone found work around for running Jest/Mocha/ codeceptjs/ webdriver io tests as part of Test plans?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [blog](https://ghoshasish99.medium.com/integrate-your-test-automation-framework-with-azure-test-plan-a3230ab0f1da) introducing Integrate test automation framework with Azure Test Plan. In order to achieve this we will make use of the Azure DevOps APIs.

> I was able to successfully integrate this set up with Java-Cucumber
> tests and Robot-Python tests. Likewise this can be extended to any JS
> framework like WebDriverIO or Cypress.

Comment: The idea im looking is to run the tests through test plans. Not just updating the result status.